# How can I load images (in img tags) from a different source than an HTTP server or a local file?

Tags: image, url, cordova, webkit

I currently have a mapping application written in Phonegap (Cordova), using OpenLayers that loads image tiles from the local file system. This works out of the box.

I would now like to load the images from another source (e.g. a database) and still use the same OpenLayers map component with  tags (DOM rendering).

I know data URIs are an option, but performance for decoding the base64 string and loading the images in general is considerably worse (less caching?). I tried this.

Is there an alternative approach? Could I somehow implement a custom protocol handler (myimagesfiles://...) and serve the binary data from some other source?

The approach would have to work on iOS and Android. Writing some native code for this would certainly be ok.

Comment: I don’t know Android/iOS, but what about the `file` URI scheme?

Comment: Yes, we currently use local files and access them over the "file:" URIs. I want to excplicitly use another source than the file system.